# DataTables icono por registro

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, datatables

Saludos a toda la comunidad!!!
Necesito mostrar en mi datatable un icono font-awesome   por cada registro de cliente almacenado. En este caso los iconos se deben mostrar en la columna Cliente y Contacto de mi tabla tal cual se ve en la imagen que adjunto.

[Listado de clientes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13TFbMsX8DTyrkKWvUrRn6pBAnCOja7oq/view?usp=drivesdk)

Éxiste la posibilidad de poder lograrlo. ?  Tienen algún ejemplo similar? Les agradezco su ayuda!!!!

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo.

Comment: Por el momento no he códificado pensé que alguien se había topado con lo mismo y me podrían dar algunas opiniones. Apenas tenga algo subiré. Debe exisitir alguna propiedad en datatables en la cual se pueda agregar un icono por cada registro

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz No puedes pedir opiniones abiertas aquí, son preguntas con respuestas concretas. Con respecto a tu cuestión, solo concatena la etiqueta `<i>` a tus resultados.

Comment: Voy a trozos jajaj. La imagen la tienes bloqueada en el drive. Deberías intentarlo antes de preguntar. Y no es solo un <i> si usas la libreria de yajra, tambien tienes que añadir la columna que uses a los raw de la config o no renderizara el html

Comment: - @Manuel Robles pude desbloquear la imagen, así es como lo necesito. Justamente estoy utilizando la librería yajra datatables. Todavía no logro comprenderlo pero probaré lo q me sugieres.

Comment: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns